# how can I reduce mux size

Tags: verilog, memory-model

```
module memory_module (input clk,input[0:6] address,input [0:7]data_input,
    input read_write,output [0:7]  data_output,input enable,output ready);
    reg ready;
    reg [0:7] data_output;
    reg [0:7] memory [127:0];

    initial
    begin
        ready=0;
    end
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if(enable)
        begin
            ready=0;
            if(read_write)
            begin
                    data_output[0:3]= memory[address][0:3];
                    data_output[4:7]= memory[address][4:7];
            end
            else
            begin
                                        memory[address][4:7]=data_input[4:7];
                                        memory[address][0:3]=data_input[0:3];
            end
            ready=1;
        end
        else
            ready=0;
    end
endmodule
```

Here is my simple verilog code for memory module design (I want to make my code more efficient)

Also when I write **data_output[0:7]= memory[address][0:7];** it creates an 8X1 mux

by writing

```
data_output[0:3]= memory[address][0:3];
data_output[4:7]= memory[address][4:7];
```

am I reducing mux size or not???

;

Answer (score 1):

No, breaking it up like that will be identical in size.

You're muxing here on the value of address, I think, so I don't understand why you think you have an 8x1 mux. You've got 128 possible addresses, so if you mux those to the output you should have an 8-bit 128-to-1 mux.

If you split it up, then you will have two 4-bit 128-to-1 muxes, which is exactly the same thing in synthesis.

Comment: Not if you want to build a 128-element dram with multiplexers. Why do you wish to reduce the size?

Comment: So I can make an  2-D array of my memory like 32X8

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand you. Are you gate constrained on whatever chip you're trying to build this on? I don't see what reducing size of muxes has to do with building a 2-D array of memory. If you need smaller RAMs, then use a DRAM, though I don't know what the end goal is.

Comment: But still I did not understand why 128x1 mux. Whenever I have to select value from memory it depends on address variable (which acts as a selecter for mux) and that is 8 bit value.

Comment: When we say an "*N-to-1*" mux, we're not talking about the width of the address, but rather the number of inputs. A 4-to-1 mux has 2 address bits and 4 data inputs. An 8-to-1 mux has 3 address bits and 8 data inputs. A 256-to-1 mux has 8 address bits and 256 data inputs.

Comment: When we design memory module our aim is to minimize mux size.That's why I want to reduce mux.Can you tell me how can I do that(I want to make efficient memory module).